# Different application layout for my rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a home page with its own style (put in `application.css`) but the rest of the website will be totally different.

Yet, it seems that Rails work with a "parent" file `application.html.erb` and we can basically use `yield` to include other `.html.erb` pages.

However, it's not viable for my application because as I said the home page will have a totally different structure from the rest of my web app and I can't use a common `application.html.erb` file.

What are the solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the layout controller wide or for a specific action.

The layout file needs to be in the `layouts` folder.

To specify the layout file controller wide you can do this

```
class BlogController < ActionController::Base
  layout "unique_blog_layout"

  def index
  end

  ...

end
```

To set it for a single view

```
class BlogController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    render layout: "unique_blog_layout"
  end

  ...
end
```

For a full rundown checkout the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and maybe [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html) too.

Answer (score 2):

To use a different layout for just a single template, do this:

1. Add your new layout to `views/layouts/name_of_my_new_layout.html.erb`
2. Use `render :index, layout: :name_of_my_new_layout` in the controller to tell Rails to use your new layout to render the template